# Does the bonus for Flawless Dawnbreaker affect melee abilities?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

[Flawless Dawnbreaker](http://esohead.com/skills/40161-flawless-dawnbreaker), one of the morphs of Dawnbreaker in the Fighter's Guild skill line, adds the effect *Passively increases your damage with weapon attacks.*

Does this affect only basic weapon attacks, i.e. Heavy and Light attack?  Or does it affect any weapon ability for the currently equipped weapon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The bonus affects all abilities and attacks that scale off weapon damage, which includes your light and heavy attacks as well as most weapon skill lines (staves excluded).

It's easy to verify yourself:

- Find an enemy that is far below your level and where you've got more than one identical copy.
- Equip a weapon based attack on your skill bar and perform it. The damage this does should cap out and be constant. In my example, *Wrecking Blow* on a low level *Skeever* does 451 damage.
- Now equip the Ultimate (or any other buff you'd like to test) and once again hit an enemy of the same type and level. Now my *Wrecking Blow* now does 508 damage.
- Now just calculate the actual gain, i.e. `gain = (100 * damage_with / damage_without) - 100`, or here: `gain = (100 * 508 / 451) - 100 = 12.639`.
- This number is a bit lower than the actual bonus (in my case it should be 13%), but that's simply a rounding error (since numbers are typically rounded down in programs).

Comment: Do you have a reference for this?

Comment: @wraith808 Gameplay experience. If I have it equipped and hit a *Skeever* with *Wrecking Blow* (Two-Handed line), I do 508 damage right now. If I unequip the Ultimate and try again, I only do 451 damage (the difference is exactly 13% once rounded). There's no random deviation and these numbers are constant since I outlevel them quite a bit.